# Как сбросить пароль проверки бэкапа в deja-dup

Tags: ubuntu, резервное-копирование

Довольно долго пользовался в Ubuntu удобной системой автоматического бэкапа на базе deja-dup. И всё было хорошо - домашний каталог бэкапился раз в неделю, при необходимости восстанавливал испорченные файлы и т.д.

Но недавно начались странные заморочки. После создания бэкапа на сервере архивов, deja-dup спрашивает пароль для проверки возможности восстановления из архива. Я предполагаю, что это пароль шифрования архива.

Раньше я всегда вводил свой обычный пароль и всё было нормально - выдавалось сообщение о том, что архив проверен и deja-dup заврешала работу.

Сейчас после ввода пароля происходит задержка секунд на 15-20 и запрос пароля повторяется. До тех пор, пока я не завершаю программу принудительно.

ну вот у меня и вопрос - как задать этот пароль, или где он хранится, что бы можно было исправить ?